# How do I initiate a call-out on metadata deployment?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api

### Overview

I would like to communicate with my team when I've deployed a change to production.

For context, let's say I'm just need to make an outbound API call to my team's Slack channel, but please ignore the outbound details.

### Details

There are three ways I can update my org (ordered here in descending frequency of use on my team):

- Force.com Migration tool (using the Metadata API)
- Administrative change
- ChangeSet
- SalesforceDX

Ideally, I'd love to listen to any of these changes  Minimally, though, I would be satisfied if I could listen to changes initiated from the Ant script in the Metadata API.  Again, all I'm looking to do afterwards is make an outbound API call which is simple.  I just need to know how to listen for it.

Comment: Have you considered some sort of CI tool like Bamboo/Jenkins? Manage Metadata Deployments with source control and have the tool send an email?

Comment: we use gearset to do this.